# Parent text wrapping beside child instead of behind it?

Tags: html, css

I will be the first to admit that I am new to this so please forgive me if this question has been answered before.  Perhaps I am not wording my question correctly to find the answer I am looking for.

I have a child container with quick reference links on the left and the text it is to reference should be in the parent on the right.  How do I get the text in the parent to wrap in the green viewable area and not across the whole parent container (behind the child)?

[Text Wrapping Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am3dX.png)

```
<div class="ministry1"><div class="ministry2">
<ol id="sidebar1">
  <li><a href="#01">The Scripture</a></li>
  <li><a href="#02">God</a>
    <ul id="side1">
      <li><a href="#001">God the Father</a></li>
      <li><a href="#002">God the Son</li>
      <li><a href="#003">God the Holy Spirit</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<li><a href="#03">Man</a></li>
<li><a href="#04">Salvation</a></li>
<li><a href="#05">God's Purpose of Grace</a></li><!--'-->
<li><a href="#06">The Church</a></li>
<li><a href="#07">Baptism and the Lord's Supper</a></li><!--'-->
<li><a href="#08">The Lord's Day</a></li><!--'-->
<li><a href="#09">The Kingdom</a></li>
<li><a href="#10">Last Things</a></li>
<li><a href="#11">Evangelism and Missions</a></li>
<li><a href="#12">Education</a></li>
<li><a href="#13">Stewardship</a></li>
<li><a href="#14">Cooperation</a></li>
<li><a href="#15">The Christian and the Social Order</a></li>
<li><a href="#16">Peace and War</a></li>
<li><a href="#17">Religious Liberty</a></li>
<li><a href="#18">The Family</a></li>
</ol></div>
<h1>Baptist Faith and Message</h1>

<p id="box">

<h3 id="01"><u>I. The Scriptures</u></h3>
```

(with LOTS more text below...)

And they are styled as follows...

```
div.ministry1 {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #99ff99; 
  border: 2px solid #660066;
  width: 1070px;
  height: 446px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.90;
}

div.ministry2 {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-right: 2px solid #660066;
  width: 225px;
  height: 446px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.90;
}

#box {
  float: right;
  padding: 8px 10px 10px 10px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything to be fixed width, the easiest possible solution will be making sidebar1 fixed and wrapping content on the right with div container with satisfying padding-left (or margin-left, it should make no difference here).

Using your containers (although I swapped box to be div, I need this element to be display: block, and it's default display for div).

```
div.ministry2 {
  position: fixed;
}

.box {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
```

You can check how this solution looks here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLyEmV

Comment: After some additional experimenting...  This solved my problem!  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that.